# conta da errado no visualg

Tags: visualg

eu to fazendo um código no Visualg pra converter Farenhight pra Celsius, só que quando eu vou testar e coloco "100" ele converte pra 68 (sendo que a resposta certa seria 37.7)

```
algoritmo "sla"

var
   F, C: real
inicio
      escreval ("qual é a temperatura aqui?")
      Leia(F)
      C<-(F-32)/1.8
      escreva ("no brasil estaria ", C:4:1)
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: parece que ele está dividindo por 1 e não 1.8. Tente colocar esse valor numa variável para divir ou para ter certeza das operações tente `((F-32)/1.8)` ou ainda veja se o visualg não espera `1,8`, faça testes e vai encontrar o problema :)

Comment: Qual versão do VISUALG você está utilizando? Testei com a versão 3.0.7 e não consegui reproduzir o problema. Ele retorna, corretamente, o valor 37.8.